# Jasmine expecting a spy, but got a Function

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm stuck being stubborn to give up and find a workaround for something that looks so simple and should be working out of the box...

I'm dealing with a Jasmine test suite using the Node environment, that is unable to spy upon an object that is clearly there/provided/imported.

I assume it's about the module resolution, and the writable property...

Can someone point me out in the proper direction, please?

For what it's worth: using Angular with testBed and stuff I never had such issues with spies, they work like...they're out of the box.

Notes:

- using prototype to spy on did not fix: *spyOn(client.prototype,'clone').and.callThrough();*
- and as you can see below, nothing gets overwritten.

Below a simplified implementation to demo.

**index.js**:
`

```
let state = null;

const templates = { obj: { a:1, b:2} },
    init = () => state = clone(templates.obj),
    clone = (obj) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

export {
    init,
    clone
}`
```

**index.spec.js**:
`

```
import * as client from '../../index.js';

describe("test", () => {
    it("should spy on the clone method", () => {
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(client));
        spyOn(client, 'clone').and.callThrough();
        client.init();
        expect(client.clone).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})`
```

**test result**:
`

```
> client@1.0.0 test
> jasmine

Randomized with seed 24629
Started
client.clone:  [Function: clone]
{
  clone: {
    value: [Function: clone],
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
  },
  init: {
    value: [Function: init],
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
  },
  [Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]: {
    value: 'Module',
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
  }
}
F

Failures:
1) test should spy on the clone method
  Message:
    Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.
    Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()`
```

Comment: You could be bumping into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049047/7365461.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but I did look into that one as I did with all posts suggested by SO. To make my point, I changed the demo below in which now a function is spied on without it being invoked by another one in the implementation to test. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
let state = null;

const templates = { obj: { a:1, b:2} },
    init = () => state = clone(templates.obj),
    clone = (obj) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

export {
    init,
    clone
}
```

index.spec.js

```
import * as client from '../../index.js';
describe("test", () => {
    it("should spy on the clone method", () => {
        spyOn(client, 'clone').and.callThrough();
        client.clone({a:1,b:2});
        expect(client.clone).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

test result
client@1.0.0 test
jasmine

Randomized with seed 76297
Started
F

Failures:
1. test should spy on the clone method
Message:
Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.
Usage: expect().toHaveBeenCalled()
Stack:
at 
at UserContext. (file:///home/masterjones/Projects/test/spec/support/index.spec.js:7:30)
at

Answer (score 0):

index.spec.js
import * as importedModule from '../../index.js';

```
const client = Object.assign({}, importedModule);

describe("test", () => {
    it("should spy on the clone method", () => {
        spyOn(client, 'clone').and.callThrough();
        client.clone({a:1,b:2});
        expect(client.clone).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})

test result:
client@1.0.0 test
jasmine

Randomized with seed 17205
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.007 seconds
Randomized with seed 17205 (jasmine --random=true --seed=17205)
```

Comment: I fixed it by copying the object, something I've never been aware of having to do so,thought this would be obvious to be handled by Jasmine: const client = Object.assign({}, importedModule);